# How to find all trustees to an asset issuing account?

Tags: assets, trustline

The goal is to find all trustees to an asset issuing account for said asset.

Example:

- **Account 1** issues `paperToken`
- **Account 2**, **3**, and **4** establish trustlines to the issuer of the `paperToken` asset

How can the JavaScript SDK be used to list all the accounts with an active trustlines to **Account1**?

Looking at the link to [StellarExpert](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/MOBI-GA6HCMBLTZS5VYYBCATRBRZ3BZJMAFUDKYYF6AH6MVCMGWMRDNSWJPIH?filter=trustlines) it clearly shows all trustlines to the `MOBI` account that have been established.

This is exactly what I would like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to run your own Stellar Core node, or query the third-party node using [GraphQL interface](https://galactictalk.org/d/885-graphql-interface-for-core-and-horizon-databases).

Information about all trustlines is located in the `trustlines` table of Core database.

Comment: I do not think you do need to run a stellar node or a third party node to get information of trustlines that have been established to an issuing account. The horizon api should be able to give you this info through pagination somehow, correct?

Comment: There is no such API endpoint. You can request this feature [here](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues) and wait until someone implements it, or write the implementation by yourself if you are familiar with GoLang.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to get a hold of through the account endpoint, and some implementation without running a core node