# Viewing trustlines for authorization required assets from an asset issuer perspective

Tags: horizon, assets, trustline

From an asset holder perspective seeing which trustlines are approved or unapproved for authorization required assets is straightforward - we can see this with the is_authorized boolean on the account balances which is very useful.

My question is: Can we do this from an asset issuer perspective? Ideally I would like to get a list of accounts that are authorized to hold your asset and also a list of accounts that have "applied" for a trustline to hold your asset via Horizon.

We can of course stream the incoming trustlines but I am looking for a way to handle any missed trustlines that doesn't require human intervention.

Comment: Older, similar question here: https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/675/how-to-find-all-trustees-to-an-asset-issuing-account but looking for any update. If the situation is unchanged I'll have a go at writing a new endpoint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good timing! In the upcoming Horizon release ([0.23](https://github.com/stellar/go/milestone/17?closed=1)) we added trustlines filtering. From the [doc](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/release-horizon-v0.23.0/services/horizon/internal/docs/reference/endpoints/accounts.md):

> This endpoint allows filtering accounts who have a given signer or have a trustline to an asset. The result is a list of accounts.
>
> To find all accounts who are trustees to an asset, pass the query parameter asset using the canonical representation for an issued assets which is `Code:IssuerAccountID`. Read more about canonical representation of assets in SEP-0011.
>
> **Note**: This endpoint is still experimental and available only if Horizon is running the new ingestion system.

Comment: That's great news. I haven't tried out the new ingestion system yet so I'll give it a whirl on our test network. Will this endpoint also return accounts that have not yet had the allow trust operation submitted to the network? The doc is missing the "is_authorized" field from the balances but I presume I would get a list of trustees and could then iterate over the list checking that bool?

Comment: I think we could potentially support both. Feature request raised here: https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/1938