# How to retrieve a list of "pending Truslines" to verify?

Tags: assets, trustline, anchor, authorization

Assume I have a [Custom Asset] that either or both of it's [Issuer/Distributor] Account(s) [Authorization required] Flag set to True.
How can I fetch a list of [Pending Trustlines] for my [Asset] in each corresponding Account in order to verify at any desired time?
BTW, I noticed an answer mentioned "trustlines filtering" "https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/viewing-trustlines-for-authorization-required-assets-from-an-asset-issuer-perspe" but didn't resolve my issue!
Stay Safe V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Horizon `/accounts` endpoint to return all the accounts with trustlines to an asset:
https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/accounts.html

You can then iterate over that list to find accounts that haven't yet been authorized.  (see https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/1938)

Comment: For those who may visit this thread later, I use "https://github.com/StellarCN/py-stellar-base", so the appropriate method for this purpose is, https://stellar-sdk-zh-cn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=_set_options_op#stellar_sdk.call_builder.AccountsCallBuilder.for_asset and notice the "pagination" aspect of the outcome in order to not miss a result.